# Upgrading to Font Awesome 5 in Salesforce

Tags: css, salesforce, visualforce, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to upgrade to FontAwesome 5 and it won't work. We run our website through OrchestraCMS that is native to Salesforce.

I've downloaded Version 5 and uploaded, as is, to my Static Resources. Then in my Visualforce Components Page Header I have added the below code:

```
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.FontAwesome, '/FontAwesome/css/fontawesome.css')}" />
```

We use [CSS pseudo elements](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#pseudo-elements), so I've updated all the classes according to the instructions:

```html
.expired::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f017";
    color: #886E3A;}
```

I've tried unzipping and uploading only the webfonts and css files, but that still doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the CSS is loaded?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded the Font Awesome file that was downloaded and the CSS that I have are coming through.

Comment: you have a link that you can share?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is in development. I am doing some other investigating and will post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation tells you everything about "Hosting Font Awesome Yourself":
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Also please note that what was for example `<i class="fa fa-home"></i>` in version 4,
that is now `<i class="fas fa-home"></i>` in version 5.
(I think this could be your main problem.)

This is also well documented here:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

After reading this two page I linked, I'm sure you will able to make it work.

Also check your browser's network tab to see if the needed css and font files for FontAwesome have been downloaded successfully. You know... no red lines and 404 :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I read all the documentation and followed the instructions. We use the CSS Pseudio class with the instructions: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#pseudo-elements. This has been followed, but I think it is the link between Salesforce and my website that is failing not the upgrade itself.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been how my website was built in Salesforce, but for those having the same problem as me, I suggest the following:
Copy the fontawesome.css (remove the '../' from the URL at the bottom of the file) and the webfonts folder into your zip file in the static resources.

Then refer to your stylesheets:

These instructions are slightly different to the Font Awesome website, as uploading their zip file and referencing it didn't work for me.